# Is there any way to copy jar files under emr master node to another location under emr master node?

Tags: hive, amazon-emr, aws-steps

I had a bootstrap script deplyed in terraform code of emr cluster creation. This bootstrap script HELPS installing QueryGrid on EMR cluster whenver there is an instance up and running. Now, to use hive connector, i need to copy jar files which got created during installation of QueryGrid to another location which is /usr/lib/hive/auxlib/ which is hive connector to be active.

I can't use bootstrap action again, as it needs first QueryGrid installation to be completed. This command below should be done only after EMR cluster creation.

I know there is steps in emr, but not sure how can i use it. Need your suggestions on this. Thanks

i MANUALLY TRIED IN EMR cluster master node, the following command, and it works. the jar files are in new location as well. I need this functionality to be applied without doing manually. We are trying to run this command as root user of EMR cluster automatically just like above Query grid.

[hadoop@ip-10-190-122-186 /]$ cd /opt/teradata/tdqg/connector/tdqg-hive-connector/02.19.00.00-3/lib/
[hadoop@ip-10-190-122-186 lib]$ ls -l
total 204
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 tdqg querygrid  61045 May  6 02:00 hive-loader-02.19.00.00-3.jar
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 tdqg querygrid  28381 May  6 02:00 hive-loaderfactory-02.19.00.00-3.jar
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 tdqg querygrid 114837 May  6 02:00 qgc-hive-02.19.00.00-3.jar

Command: sudo cp /opt/teradata/tdqg/connector/tdqg-hive-connector/02.19.00.00-3/lib/*.jar /usr/lib/hive/auxlib/

I did added this above command in a new file as shell script and uploaded it into s3 location of EMR , s3://my-bucketname/QueryGridInstallation/my-shellscript.sh

i am stuck which type of step can be used here, and what can be jar location, and argument that can be passed and executes as root user in executing this command.